# Access - Sort by a combination of fields

Tags: sql, sorting, ms-access

I had (see below) a table of (fictional) stars and then two tables showing its equally fictional satellites which could be planets or asteroid belts.  `tblStars`, `tblAsteroids` and `tblPlanets` respectively.  Each of the two satellite tables had a position field which was unique across the two tables - by this I mean that the star with ID 1 had only one satellite in position 1, 2 etc which could have been in either of those two tables but not both.  I wanted to sort the satellites in order of position on my reports but couldn't see a way of sorting across the combination of those fields:

```
tblAsteroid:
Asteroid ID    Position
1               1
2               3

tblPlanet:
Planet ID       Position       Biome
1               2              Ice

Giving:
Position        AsteroidOrPlanet     Biome
1               Asteroid             N/A
2               Planet               Ice
3               Asteroid             N/A
```

---

For the avoidance of doubt, I recognise that this problem was caused by a flaw in my database design and I should have had a `tblSatellite` which contained that position and was in a 1 to many with `tblStar` and in 1 to 0-1's with `tblAsteroid` and `tblPlanet`.  I've since fixed this, I'm just wondering if it *would* have been possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a combined list, you need a UNION query anyway. This you can sort by a common field.

```
SELECT Position, 'Asteroid' AS AsteroidOrPlanet, 'N/A' AS Biome
FROM tblAsteroid

UNION ALL

SELECT Position, 'Planet' AS AsteroidOrPlanet, Biome
FROM tblPlanet

ORDER BY Position
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you for indulging my curiosity.